# How does Spring Data JdbcTemplate add value to a MySQL JSON column?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Currently I am using

```java
mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("someJsonColumn", _objectMapper.writeValueAsString(somePOJO));
```

But this doesn't seem to be the right practice, since it's essentially storing a String object in the column.

However, using

```java
mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("someJsonColumn", somePOJO)
```

would give SQL error saying it doesn't match the JSON column type.

What's the right practice to store a POJO to a JSON column in MySQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

POJO is `Plain Old Java Object`. A table `row` represents a POJO where the column values are the attributes if that object. Here, you are trying to map a `column` with an object. It shouldn't work. Try mapping an attribute of that object. For example,

```
mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("someJsonColumn", somePOJO.getSomeAttribute());
```